# How to list target_link_libraries available on a system?

Tags: linux, curl, cmake

I'm trying to link with the Curl library in my CMakeLists.txt and I know that I should require the package add executable and link the library but I don't know how the variables names are called and where should I look for them, do you know where should I be looking for? Is there a way to list all the libraries in the system that I could be able to add in my project?

Here it's my CMakeLists (silly) attempt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(RadekClientRecon)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
link_directories(/usr/lib/)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp HttpManager.cpp)
add_executable(RadekClientRecon ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(RadekClientRecon ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

I've searched all "curl" named files in my computer if helps, I'm also using CLion if there's an automated way.

```
rinaldi@rinaldi-home:~/Projects/radekrecon$ sudo find / -name "*curl*" 2> /dev/null 
/home/rinaldi/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/jscs/lib/rules/disallow-curly-braces.js
/home/rinaldi/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/jscs/lib/rules/require-curly-braces.js
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pycurl.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3-gnutls:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/curl.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pycurl.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3-gnutls:amd64.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3-gnutls:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3:amd64.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3-gnutls:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pycurl.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/curl.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pycurl.prerm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3-gnutls:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3-gnutls:amd64.list
/opt/clion-1.2.4/bin/cmake/doc/cmake-3.3/cmcurl
/opt/clion-1.2.4/bin/gdb/lib/python2.7/macurl2path.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/macurl2path.py
/usr/lib/python3.5/macurl2path.py
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.3.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstcurl.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pycurl.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/curl
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pycurl-7.19.5.1.egg-info
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pycurl.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3.4/macurl2path.py
/usr/lib/gnupg/gpgkeys_curl
/usr/bin/curl
/usr/share/man/man1/curl.1.gz
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libcurl3
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libcurl3-gnutls
/usr/share/doc/libcurl3
/usr/share/doc/python3-pycurl
/usr/share/doc/libcurl3-gnutls
/usr/share/doc/curl
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/curl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I needed to install some packages other than curl.

```
 * libcurl4-gnutls-dev
 * libcurl4-nss-dev
 * libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Those variables are named after their modules that can be found [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-modules.7.html).
My CMakeList.txt now it's creating the proper make file and looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(RadekClientRecon)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
link_directories(/usr/lib/)
link_directories(CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp HttpManager.cpp)
add_executable(RadekClientRecon ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(RadekClientRecon ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

Comment: This line is useless `link_directories(CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS)` and I believe you also don't need this one: `link_directories(/usr/lib/)`

Answer (score 0):

After verifying the installation of curl, this is my CMakeLists.txt, which is running well on ubuntu 17.10

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CURL_MIN_VERSION "7.55.1")

project(Downloader)

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

link_directories(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/)

add_executable(Downloader HTTPDownloaderExample.cpp HTTPDownloader.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Downloader curl)
```